# How to find if image is inside a carousel or image slider using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

- So basically i have two examples below. What i want to achieve is to find out if any image resides or is a part of a carousel or image slider on any site using javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adunits.datawrkz.com/tmstest/data/placement/placement_33.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>

<h2>Manual Slideshow</h2>

<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px;position:relative">

 <img class="mySlides" src="http://cdn1.uvnimg.com/dims4/default/df2c09d/2147483647/resize/956x717%3E/quality/75/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn3.uvnimg.com%2F19%2Fe5%2Faf29e5954db3a59373665dc6c8cf%2Fresizes%2F1500%2Fdsc03357.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <img class="mySlides" src="http://cdn1.uvnimg.com/dims4/default/45e76a5/2147483647/resize/956x717%3E/quality/75/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn1.uvnimg.com%2F5a%2Ff3%2F4bbeacb547f9acd4cfc6818bfa81%2Fresizes%2F1500%2Fdsc03368.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <img class="mySlides" src="http://cdn4.uvnimg.com/dims4/default/c20279d/2147483647/resize/956x717%3E/quality/75/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn1.uvnimg.com%2F32%2F48%2F1785731948b1b5e9f186c3e7404c%2Fresizes%2F1500%2Fdsc03376.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <img class="mySlides" src="http://cdn2.uvnimg.com/dims4/default/a4883a5/2147483647/resize/956x717%3E/quality/75/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn3.uvnimg.com%2F6e%2Fa6%2F5e24000548119acf7ec7e2be7aa8%2Fresizes%2F1500%2Fdsc03353.jpg" style="width:100%">

 <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:0" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</a>
 <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:0" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}


 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://cdn1.uvnimg.com/dims4/default/df2c09d/2147483647/resize/956x717%3E/quality/75/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn3.uvnimg.com%2F19%2Fe5%2Faf29e5954db3a59373665dc6c8cf%2Fresizes%2F1500%2Fdsc03357.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn1.uvnimg.com/dims4/default/45e76a5/2147483647/resize/956x717%3E/quality/75/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn1.uvnimg.com%2F5a%2Ff3%2F4bbeacb547f9acd4cfc6818bfa81%2Fresizes%2F1500%2Fdsc03368.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn4.uvnimg.com/dims4/default/c20279d/2147483647/resize/956x717%3E/quality/75/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn1.uvnimg.com%2F32%2F48%2F1785731948b1b5e9f186c3e7404c%2Fresizes%2F1500%2Fdsc03376.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn2.uvnimg.com/dims4/default/a4883a5/2147483647/resize/956x717%3E/quality/75/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn3.uvnimg.com%2F6e%2Fa6%2F5e24000548119acf7ec7e2be7aa8%2Fresizes%2F1500%2Fdsc03353.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

- The above are samples. I want to put an ad on sites finding the first image of carousel. Ad i have in place. Will just need to find images are in carousel or slider.
- So any suggestions ? Also check link below.

  http://www.univision.com/deportes/fantasy/el-top-10-de-los-jugadores-de-la-fecha-4-del-univision-deportes-fantasy-del-a2016-fotos

Comment: if you have the img as an element, the parent is in the DOM, so you could just go through all parents until you find some carousel/slider class... ?